# Pandas(Python) : How to fill empty cells with previous row value with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For order dataset where Customer name (**Name**) per order are not repeated and some order does not have customer name.
Example :

[image]

How can I make the name is repeated like :

[image]

I wonder if it's still possible to use  `ffill()` with condition that order id should be the same

Comment: please share data so that it can be copy-pasted.

Comment: groupby ffill and recombine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596674/python-pandas-groupby-ffill-for-multiple-columns/55597316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'order id':['A1','A1','A2','A3'],'Name':['Adam',np.nan,np.nan,'su']})
df['Name']=df['Name'].groupby(df['order id']).fillna(method='ffill')

df
Out[28]: 
  order id  Name
0       A1  Adam
1       A1  Adam
2       A2   NaN
3       A3    su
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. Previously, i did something like : `test('shipping_customer_name')=test.sort_values('order_creation_datetime').groupby('order_id')['shipping_customer_name'].fillna(method='pad') 
`  Completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use groupby and then fill. If you want to apply the fill operation only on the "Name" column, it should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {"order_id": [1,1,2,3], "name":["adam", np.nan, np.nan, "Su"],"total":            [15,np.nan, 5, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["name"] = df.groupby("order_id")["name"].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
DataFrame.fillna(method="ffill", axis=1, limit=1)
```